# Swift iOS12 App not starting download of large mp3

Tags: swift, download, mp3, nsurlsession, ios12

we have an app that should download large (150Mb) mp3 files. But in around 50% of instances, the download fails to start when requested.

Here is the code:

```
let testUrl = URL(string: downloadURL)!

       let bgTask = bgSession.downloadTask(with: 
        testUrl)

       if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        bgTask.countOfBytesClientExpectsToSend = 200
        } else {
              // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
       bgTask.resume()
```

1. When the issue appears, the mp3 file can always be downloaded to the same ipad through a browser, so this means that

   - the link is available (We use https now, but http should work).
   - there is no server issue
   - there is no connectivity issue with the ipad.
2. Other apps are unaffected (bbc, netflix can still download), so there must be a solution.
3. The issue happens when the app is open. So the bug is not just related to "background" downloading.
4. The issue isn't just with displaying progress, it's with the actual downloading.
5. It appears seemingly randomly. IFAIK it is only an issue with iOS12, not previous iOS.
6. Once the issue hits, nothing (reboot, reload, refresh, reinstall app) seems to work. If it is left for an hour it then seems to download (90% of the time).

Any suggestions on code, more tests, anything would be a great help, we've been trying to solve this issue for over a month!
 Many thanks.

Comment: Background URLSession app wakeups are rate limited, with exponential backoff. You could be running foul of that: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/42352 It's very easy to do during the development cycle or if you chain your downloads.

Comment: “the download fails to start when requested“ ... Does it it really fail or just not start as soon as you’d like? Is this a [discretionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411552-isdiscretionary) download? Or are you running this while the app is running in background (which makes it discretionary)?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, @RhythmicFistman: No it's a foreground issue, i.e. with the app open, click download, that's when the issue happens.

Comment: @Rob it's not a discretionary download: We're not setting is as discretionary, and it's in foreground. Re: Does it really fail: I retested:
If I'm at 70% WiFi signal, it won't start. If I move towards the router, it will start as the signal increases. Once it's started, the download won't stop until completed (even if I walk back to the weaker signal). This is repeatable.

So actually that's enough to work around, thanks for the prompt to retest. It doesn't explain why other apps (BBC iPlayer good example) can start the download in weaker signal than our app. Any ideas greatly received.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of the problem @IanC ?